# What is the PowerShell equivalent of bash's exec()?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, exec

Newbie to PowerShell here. What's the best way to run a new script from within the current process without creating a subshell? In Bash, you would do this via:

```
source script # Executes the commands in script within the current shell
```

or

```
exec script # Same as source, except it completely replaces the current process with script
```

Is there an equivalent for this in PowerShell?

Comment: don't know bash.. but you may want to check out "dot sourcing" in PowerShell.

Comment: Unlike bash, a script can be run in a different scope without starting a subshell. That is what just specifying the script name does. Whereas "dot sourcing" causes the scrip to run in the same scope as caller (like bash). See `about_scope` for details on PS scoping. Also the "call operator" `&` (see `help about_operators`) interprets its argument as something that can be executed (be it a string which is script, a variable whose value is a script block, or just a plain command name) and executes it in a new scope (if it is a PS script) or new process (if it is an executable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `.\Script.ps1`

Or start typing the name and use `TAB` to complete the script name.

Dot-sourcing a script allows a function to become available on the command line.

For example:

```
Function Get-LocalTime { 

$CurTime = Get-Date

"The Date and time currently is $CurTime"

}
```

Now we dot source (name the above script Example.ps1) `PS C:\>. .\Example.ps1`

Allowing us to simply type and Tab complete `Get-LocalTime`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAHmS.png]

-edit to comment, you can define a function and use the function immediately in the same script.  So in `Example.ps1`, at the last line just enter `Get-LocalTime`

Comment: This answers the first half of the question (powershell equivalent to source), but doesn't answer the title. Is there an equivalent to `exec`? This would be super useful for making an alias to run bash where you don't have to `exit` twice.

Comment: For Windows admins who are not familiar with Unix exec(), it passes the execution context completely to the child, and the parent is no longer occupying memory as a process. If we do a ps, the original powershell process should disappear. This is super-useful because sometimes we want to do things before starting up services, but do not want the parent shell hanging around.